# Desktop Application that can sync files from dropbox, google drive, onedrive, icloud

Tags: cross-platform, cloud-service, desktop-client, google-drive, dropbox

Currently I'm having to download a client for each of the cloud services to be able to manage & sync files.

I am looking for a single cross platform desktop application that can manage & sync files, documents & photos from dropbox, google drive, onedrive & icloud.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question since no one has answered it.

Check out [odrive](https://www.odrive.com/) - Sync all cloud storage in one place.

### Features

- Available on Windows, Mac & Linux.
- Supports Dropbox, Google Drive, Onedrive, iCloud & many more
- Sync multiple account - Consolidate multiple accounts from the same service. Sync your personal, work, and project accounts to one place for easy access.